# Unknown module(s) in QT: multimedia

Tags: c++, qt, qtmultimedia

I have downloaded qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.1 and build and installed static.
Next i built QMultimedia and installed.

I get "Unknown module(s) in QT: multimedia" from the .pro when including 
QT += multimedia.

I have QtMultimedia,QtMultimediaQuick_p and QtMultimediaWidgets in /usr/local/Qt-5.4.1/include.
Also have mediaservice,playlistformats in /usr/local/Qt-5.4.1/plugins
Also have QtMobility,QtMultimediaKit in /usr/include

I am running Ubuntu 15.0

All related issues i've found did not help.

Comment: Make sure qtmm is enabled when you configure Qt, maybe it couldn't find a suitable backend. Includes might be installed either way, watch out for the qtmm .so files

Comment: how do i check if qtmm is enabled? do i have to build again?

Comment: Rerun configure and check its summary

Comment: summary of ./configure        http://pastebin.com/KkmCd37c

Answer (score 11):

Please run:

```
sudo apt-get install qtmultimedia5-dev
```

afterwards you can install other multimedia packages as needed, but this enables the multimedia in general.

Comment: I had on one machine a `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQt5Multimedia` error, which was caused by a broken link in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, where the `libQt5Multimedia.so` points to a non-existing version (5.2.1 in my case).
Please check the link beforehand. To check run a `ls -la /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Do not copy and paste the following command without double-check.
The command, which fixes the issue in my case was: `( cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu; ln -sf libQt5Multimedia.so.5.1.1 libQt5Multimedia.so )`.