# Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: multimedia multimediawidgets on MacOS

Tags: c++, qt, qtmultimedia

I am trying to use the Qt Multimedia API to access the user's webcam, but when I run the qmake, QT Creator says that the modules `multimedia` and `multimediawidgets` are unknown.

[image]

How can I install these modules on MacOS? I found a way to do it on Linux [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817619/unknown-modules-in-qt-multimedia) but not on MacOS.

Comment: how did you install Qt?

Comment: what is your Qt Version?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I downloaded from [this page](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source?hsCtaTracking=9f6a2170-a938-42df-a8e2-a9f0b1d6cdce%7C6cb0de4f-9bb5-4778-ab02-bfb62735f3e5).

Comment: @eyllanesc Qt Creator 5.0.1 based on Qt 5.15.2.

Comment: That QtCreator has been compiled with Qt5 does not imply that you are using Qt5. I suspect that you have installed Qt6.

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes, you're right. I installed Qt6, which is the one that was installed by default. Should I install an earlier version?

Comment: Only in Qt 6.2 will the multimedia modules and multimediawidgets be available, so I recommend using the latest version of Qt5, not Qt6.

Answer (score 0):

Since Qt6, multimedia needs to be installed additionally. You can install it using the qt maintenance tool and find it under "additional libraries"